# Converting dataset value to decimal

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Exchange rate is decimal type property ,in the runtime i m getting an error when assigning value to the exchange rate property . Error is "Input string was not in correct format".

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {

            if (dr["Rate"] != null)
            {
                accountTransactionHistory.ExchangRate = decimal.Parse(dr["Rate"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you a problem with regional setting? ',' instead of '.'?

Comment: What type of column is Rate in the database?

Comment: it's a decimal column

Answer (score 0):

use

```
accountTransactionHistory.ExchangRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Rate"].ToString());
```